# Creating query that finds how many redID's match to each employeeID

Tags: sql

I have a SQL Server that records employees/visitors. We have two different tables for each. I would like to display a count of how many visitors are associated with each employee. Their is a matching identifier in each table which is `EmployeeID`.

My tables looks like this

From Visitor

```
[row#][RecId][EmployeeId]
```

obviously other information is in their in between each of those columns.

From Employee

```
[row#][RecId][Id]
```

Comment: It would be nice if you put what you've already tried and which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select e.*,
       (select count(*) from visitors v where v.employeeid = e.id) as num_visitors
from employee e;
```